# Cardinality of the set of all involutions from $\mathbb N$ to itself

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

The following is a section in my homework, I couldnt solve it so I'm asking for some help.

I have the following set : $\{f:\mathbb N \to \mathbb N | f(f(a)) = a \text{ for all } a\in \mathbb N\}$.

I need to find if this set is a finite set, countably infinite set ($\aleph_0$) or infinite and uncountable.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:** Prove that there exists one such $f$ for which $f(x)\neq x$, for all $x$. Then use this fact to show that for every infinite $A\subseteq\Bbb N$, there exists a function $f_A$ such that $f_A(a)\neq a\iff a\in A$; and $f_A(f_A(a))=a$ for every $a\in\Bbb N$.

Comment: תודה רבה
Thanks, it gave me an idea, I will try to work it out.
Greetings from the Technion :P

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: I have no clue how to type in "readable math symbols" so im sorry in advance.

Can I say that for every A={0,1,..,n}, the function is the constant function f(i)=n+1 and therefore f(i) always differs from i, and continue from here ?

Comment: No, you cannot. Because you want $f$ to still have the property $f(f(a))=a$ for every $a$.

Comment: And what about using the (mod n) ? lets say, for every A={0,1,..,n} , f(i)=(i+n/2)modn , therefore f(f(i))=i

Comment: You have to stop thinking in terms of finite sets (see how my hint disregards them completely). Most sets are not finite, and their complement is not finite. Have you found $f\colon\Bbb N\to\Bbb N$ with the wanted property? Once you have that, things are easier to define.

Comment: Couldnt find one :\ 
Would you mind giving me another hint ?

Comment: Split $\Bbb N$ into pairs.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** There is an injection from the set of binary strings that have infinitely many of both $1$s and $0$s, to the set of functions $f = f^{-1}$. Note that the latter is equivalent to the set of partitions of $\mathbb N$ into sets of disjoint pairs.

Answer (score 0):

One step beyond: This set is, at least, infinite countable (Alef-sub0).
For every pair (n,m) of natural numbers (and they are Alef-sub0) we define f(n)=m and f(m)=n, out of this the function is the identify, i.e. f(x)=x.
I guess we can go furher and prove the cardinal of this set is c, but I need to go to beed now.
Hope it helps.